# Ruby loop - determining value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looping through some items, the names should be self explanatory:

```
  <% [@in_force_item, @draft_item, @historical_items].compact.flatten.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label><input class="select"  type="checkbox" /></label>
        </td>
       <td>
          <% if item == @draft_item %>
            <div> <%= link_to('', edit_account_item_path(@account, @draft_loa_item), class: 'black-icon-color') %></div>
          <% else %>
                  <i class="lock"></i>
              <span class='black-icon-color'></span>
          <% end %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <% updated_at = datetime_to_string item.updated_at %>
           <%= link_to(updated_at, account_item_path(@account, item)) %>
        </td>
        <td><%= lifecycle_label(item) %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

the line I am having trouble with is checking if the item is a draft.

```
<% if item == @draft_item %>
```

This doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure how to go about it.  Do I need a method in my Item model to check if its a draft or not?

How can I achieve this?

Edit:  the model has this:

```
    COMPOSITE_DRAFT = [LIFECYCLE_DRAFT_NUM, LIFECYCLE_RETURNED_NUM]
LIFECYCLE_DRAFT_NAME = 'Draft'
LIFECYCLE_DRAFT_NUM = 0
 LIFECYCLE_RETURNED_NAME = 'Returned'
  LIFECYCLE_RETURNED_NUM = 2
```

so I should be able to use something like:

```
item.lifecycle_num.????
```

Comment: When you say "This doesn't seem to work" - what is your actual problem?

Comment: sorry I had the value in the database wrong - I have requested to close this

Answer (score 0):

Your items should have states,- that way you'd be able to call `item.draft?` method and also, you wouldn't need the three separate instance variables. Please check the [aasm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) gem for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all three are ActiveRecord objects, you can check `item.id == @draft_item.id`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, each of '@in_force_item, @draft_item, @historical_items' is array too. Yes?

Therefore, when You do `[@in_force_item, @draft_item, @historical_items].flatten` as result You get new array with elements from '@in_force_item, @draft_item, @historical_items' arrays. The array '@draft_item' absent in this new array, but 'elements of this' are present.

So, You could write:

```
  <% if @draft_item.include? (item) %>
```